# electrostatics numerical

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Two insulated copper spheres have their centers separated by a distance of 50cm. If charge on each sphere is 6.5×10⁷C, what is the mutual force of repulsion when the spheres are **placed in water?**
The radii of the spheres are negligible compared to the distance of separation.

Comment: What do you think about this problem?

Comment: what is the significance of the spheres placed in water?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dielec.html

Comment: Did you check the homework policy? http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that forces between spheres do not change, just that water gets polarised and the **net** force changes. If you wish to find this net force, just use permittivity of water in stead of vacuum in your formula.